# How to easily insert Excel spreadsheet into web page?

Tags: html, excel

I would like to insert an Excel spreadsheet into a Web page but would like to change some of the data at the same time to make them more user friendly.

Is it easily possible?

Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 1):

Excel can export HTML files directly ("Save as...") What modification exactly do you want to do? Can you do them by hand? Do you want to automate them (how often you want to do the export?)

For small modifications, it's relatively easy to write a VBA macro (or just record it..).

Comment: A few of the data contained in the Excel spreadsheet need to be manually changed before putting the table on the Web, otherwise they would not be understood by visitors. 
I do not understand what is the easiest method to convert the Excel spreadsheet, change a few data and put the result on a web page as a table.

Comment: I'd probably change the data in the excel sheet before converting, then use "Save as ..." and choose HTML as output format. The resulting HTML file can be directly put on the web server.

Answer (score 0):

If you don't mind the security risks, you can activate ActiveX and embed the Excel spreadsheet in the web page using the `<object>` element (see [these forum posts](http://www.webmasterworld.com/forum21/11286.htm) for some pointers). **Don't browse the Internet with ActiveX enabled! You *will* get a virus or Trojan.**

Note that the spreadsheet must be on a network drive that is accessible by all users.

If that isn't an option, then try [Zoho Sheet](http://sheet.zoho.com/) or [Google Docs](http://docs.google.com/). Drawback: You must give your previous data to a third party.

Last option: Use a web server to convert the Excel into HTML and use a JavaScript grid control.

Comment: OK.  You mean I could import my Excel spreadsheet into Google docs, modify what data I want to modify but then how can I put the result into my page?

Comment: Follow these instructions: http://docs.google.com/support/bin/answer.py?hl=en&answer=55244